# Is a US patent (US D765,756 S) covering Europe?

Tags: patent-infringment

I'm in the importing process for products from China and I discovered patent **US D765,756 S**. It's a patent from Taiwan, registered in the US.

Does US D765,756 S apply in Europe? What does S at the end mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [kind code](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/electronic-business-center/kind-codes-included-uspto-patent) at the end "S" simply means it's a design patent. Just like the "D" at the beginning.

This one has a Taiwanese priority which I can't locate, but neither [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=US&NR=D765756S&KC=S&FT=D&ND=3&date=20160906&DB=&locale=en_EP) nor [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD765756S1/en?oq=US%20D765%2C756%20S) list any family members, so there are probably none. Which means that this design patent is only valid in the US, but as it's relatively young, there could be older ones.

Answer (score 0):

The cited document is a US design patent and is only in effect in the US. I couldn’t find an equivalent design patent for the EU but it doesn’t mean there might not be other relevant IP.